# foreign key error <table constraint> expected error

Tags: android, sqlite, foreign-keys, android-sqlite

I just want to create these tables with foreign key but i got error like  expected, got 'quantity'. I already try solution given by another posts but still won't work.

here is the code :

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE user(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, username TEXT, password TEXT, email TEXT, phone TEXT)");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE transactions(TRANSACTIONS_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, userID INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES user(ID), quantity TEXT)");
    }
```

Comment: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research in posts. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0):

`FOREIGN KEY ....` is a table level clause and must follow all the column level clauses and therefore should follow the definition of the **quantity** column.

So either:-

```
CREATE TABLE transactions(TRANSACTIONS_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, userID INTEGER, quantity TEXT, FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES user(ID))
```

Or you can define the foreign key at the column level using:-

```
CREATE TABLE transactions(TRANSACTIONS_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, userID INTEGER REFERENCES user(ID), quantity TEXT)
```

- as you can see at the column level you just use REFERENCES  table(column)

  - you cannot define complex/composite foreign keys at the column level, they can only be defined at the table level.
- See [CREATE TABLE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) and expand (click on Show) the respective sections

  - for column level expand column_def and column_constraint and foreign_key_clause
  - for table level expand table_constraint and foreign_key_clause
  - noting that the foreign key clause itself is the same for both